# Material Library to use with React(and MongoDB) instead of Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern, material-components-web

> Hi everyone. I am currently building a new project using React, MongoDB and Express (MERN Stack basics)
> Is there any other recommendations as to what material library source I can use, to veer away from Bootstrap.
> With Angular, it's Angular Material is ofcourse a winner, but I am specifically looking for React Material Libraries without hassles.
> Please leave your recommendations for me, I'd appreciate it tremendously!

Answer (score 1):

You can use mui library src is [MUI](https://mui.com/system/styled/)

MUI comes with dozens of ready-to-use components in the core. These components are an incredible starting point but when it comes to making your site stand out with a custom design, it can be simpler to start from an unstyled state. Introducing the system:

The system lets you quickly build custom UI components leveraging the values defined in your theme.